# appium python error:This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, appium

chrome://inspect/#devices in Chrome Browser show: 
M2010J19SC #44DDF4470121 
WebView in com.tencent.mm (77.0.3865.120) trace 
 
when I run

```
driver.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW_com.tencent.mm:tools')
```

Appium run failed:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
Original error: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83.
My Google Chrome Version：Version 90.0.4430.93（64 bit）

Appium log：

```
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m The most recent known Chrome version: 86.0.4240
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Found 6 executables in 'C:\Users\LinHai\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win'[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m The following Chromedriver executables were found:
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     'C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver-原始.exe' (version '86.0.4240.22', minimum Chrome version '86.0.4240')
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     'C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver_win32_v83.0.4103.39.exe' (version '83.0.4103.39', minimum Chrome version '83.0.4103')
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     'C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver.exe' (version '83.0.4103.39', minimum Chrome version '83.0.4103')
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     'C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver_win32_v83.0.4103.14.exe' (version '83.0.4103.14', minimum Chrome version '83.0.0')
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     'C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver_win32_v2.44.exe' (version '2.44', minimum Chrome version '69.0.3497')
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     'C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver_win32_v2.43.exe' (version '2.43', minimum Chrome version '69.0.3497')
```

I tried to change 
C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver.exe
的chromedriver.exe to below versions:
77.0.3865.40
83.0.4103.39
86.0.4240.22
90.0.4430.24

still returns 'This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83' error

Must I have to downgrade Chrome version to 83?

Comment: Did you try updating the drivers?

Comment: Yes,I download ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22,and replace 'C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver.exe'

Answer (score 0):

just update your chromedriver - https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: which version of chromedriver shall I update?

Comment: the one compatible with your chrome - therefore ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24

Comment: I replace ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24,but it still 'The most recent known Chrome version: 86.0.4240'  ,  'C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver.exe' (version '90.0.4430.24', minimum Chrome version '90')

Comment: then you're doing something wrong - this kind of issue has only one solution...you might have different locations with diffferent chromedrivers in it...just looking at your Appium log, I don't see the 90 version there

Comment: [debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m Found 6 executables in 'C:\Users\LinHai\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win'[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m The following Chromedriver executables were found:
[debug] [35m[Chromedriver][39m     'C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/chromedriver.exe' (version '90.0.4430.24', minimum Chrome version '90')

Answer (score 0):

Use [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to auto-update the driver:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

To install/update the ChromeDriver:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

custom_path = '/home/user/drivers/chromedriver'
ChromeDriverManager(path=custom_path).install()
```

Comment: where shall  I input these code? before self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", self.dc) ?

Comment: custom_path = 'C:\\Users\\LinHai\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-chromedriver\\chromedriver\\win\\chromedriver.exe'                             
ChromeDriverManager(path=custom_path).install()

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] system can not find specified location : 'C:\\Users\\LinHai\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-chromedriver\\chromedriver\\win\\chromedriver.exe\\drivers'

Comment: custom_path = 'D:\\CLX\\Android\\chromedriver\\90.0.4430.24\\chromedriver_win32'
        ChromeDriverManager(path=custom_path).install()

Comment: ====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 90.0.4430
Get LATEST driver version for 90.0.4430
Driver [D:\CLX\Android\chromedriver\90.0.4430.24\chromedriver_win32\drivers\chromedriver\win32\90.0.4430.24\chromedriver.exe] found in cache    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: A new session could not be created. Details: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83

Comment: Did you try instaling the drivers un this path: C:/Users/LinHai/AppData/Local/Programs/Appium/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/win/? I think You have 2 installs of chromedriver and one of them si not update.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by anding below code:

```
self.dc['chromedriverExecutable'] = 'D:\\chromedriver\\should be the same with app's webview version\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'
```